# Does Spring @Transactional annotated on method ensure the flush of data exactly when the method ends?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have this simplified escenario in a Spring application with Java and Hibernate for persistence provider:

```
@Transactional
void method1() { // some savings}

@Transactional
void method2() { // some savings}
```

When I run a parent method (not annotated as transactional)

```
void parentMethod() {
    method1();
    method2();
}
```

Can I make sure that when the method finishes the changes are impacted in the database immediately before the method is called? 
Or that changes could be flush to database later, with some delay?

I'm interested on other applications seeing the changes made in database immediately when method1 finishes (and before method2 be called)

**Update**
My parent method is not defined in the same class, and the class and firm of the my parent method has not @Transactional annotation

Thanks!

Comment: @mentallurg thanks! But it's a different question, with different characteristics. It's not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 7):

To your question *... ensure the flush of data exactly when the method ends*? No, not *exactly* when the method ends, but *latest* when the method ends.

Within transaction you can flush the current state as many times as you wish. Flushing means that you synchronize your JPA session with database. See [Hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/flushing/Flushing.html) regarding this. Flushing does not mean your changes are durable; if transaction rolls back later on, these changes will be automatically reverted. The *commit* operation performs different steps, one of them is to ensure that the JPA (e.g. Hibernate) session is synchronized with DB, and, if needed, calls flush. If the session is already synchronized, flush will be skipped.

In the comments you wrote that the class and the method `parentMethod` are not transactional and that `method1()` and `method2()` are defined in a separate class. In such case when the `method1()` is called, a new transaction will be started. When this method ends, this transaction will be committed. Any changes in the database done by this method will be *durable*, i.e. no matter what happens later on (exceptions, roll backs in other methods) these changes will remain in the database.

Some information relevant to your case can be found [here](http://It%20is%20a%20duplicate%20because%20it%20is%20important%201)%20If%20%20these%20methods%20are%20in%20the%20same%20class%20or%20not%20and%202)%20If%20you%20use%20Spring%20own%20AOP%20or%20AspectJ.%20Besides%20it%20depends%20on%20the%20class%20where%20your%20%60parentMethod%60%20is%20defined.%20If%20it%20is%20transactional,%20then%20these%202%20calls%20will%20run%20within%20the%20existing%20transaction%20and%20there%20will%20be%20no%20commit) because following is important:

1. If  these methods are in the same class or not and
2. If you use Spring own AOP or AspectJ. Besides it depends on the class where your `parentMethod` is defined. If it is transactional, then these 2 calls will run within the existing transaction and there will be no commit after the 1st one is committed.

Comment: Thanks, two questions on it: 1) @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW) should "suspend" the parent transaction until the child finishes (regarding to Transactional javadoc), not force commit 2) Are you understanding Commit as an equal for a Flush? I will update the question with more details about the points you mentioned

Comment: 1) Yes, it will suspend the outer transaction. But when the nested is method is completed, its transaction will be committed (or rolled back in case of error) before the outer transaction resumes. I.e. before `method2()` is called the transaction used for `method1()` will be committed. 2) With *commit* I mean that changes will be made *durable*. No matter what happens afterwards the durable changes will not be reverted. Commit is not equal to flush. You can trigger flush even without committing the transaction. But when commit is executed, it will also trigger flush if it is needed.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies! Do you know how to force flush when @Transactional method finishes?

Comment: You don't need to manually flush, because `commit` will do that for you.